# Weird stuttering issues not related to GC

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I am getting some odd stuttering issues with my game even though my FPS never seems to drop below 30. About every 5 seconds my game stutters. I was originally getting stuttering every 1-2 seconds due to my garbage collection issues, but I have sorted those and will often go 15-20 seconds without a garbage collection.

Despite this, my game still stutters periodically even when there is no GC listed in logcat anywhere near the stutter. Even when I take out most of my code and simply make my "physics" code the below code I get this weird slowdown issue. I feel that I am missing something or overlooking something.

Shouldn't that "elapsed" code that I put in stop any variance in the speed of the main character related to changes in FPS?

Any input/theories would be awesome.

Physics:

```
private void updatePhysics()
{
    //get current time
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

    //added this to see if I could speed it up, it made no difference
    Thread myThread = Thread.currentThread();
    myThread.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);

    //work out elapsed time since last frame in seconds
    double elapsed = (now - mLastTime2) / 1000.0;

    mLastTime2 = now;

    //measures FPS and displays in logcat once every 30 frames
    fps+=1/elapsed;
    fpscount+=1;

    if (fpscount==30)
    {
        fps=fps/fpscount;
        Log.i("myActivity","FPS: "+fps+" Touch: "+touch);
        fpscount=0;
    }

    //this should make the main character (theoretically) move upwards at a steady pace
    mY-=100*elapsed;

    //increase amount I translate the draw to = main characters Y 
    //location if the main character goes upwards
    if (mY<=viewY)
    {
        viewY=mY;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you're seeing? Does your character still move at the correct pace (but with jerky motion), or does the character's movement actually slow down?

Comment: It appears to actually slow down most of the time. Sometimes it stutters (when the GC occasionally runs). I have noticed that if I close everything on my phone with taskiller it slows down far less. Nothing is appearing in my logcat log while it is running though. It is very weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `Log.i()` call, if you haven't already!

Edit:

Alternatively, remove the floating point. `elapsed` doesn't need to be double, just keep an integer count of milliseconds instead. You can then use `mY-=100*elapsed/1000;` in your movement calculation, and comment out or remove the other floating point calculations (`fps`, `fpscount`).

Comment: Sadly that doesn't make any difference. One of the first things I tried.

Comment: I tried changing to integers, it seems to have increased the performance a tad, but I still get the slowdowns. As mentioned above, if I turn the phone off, then on, and close as many applications as I possibly can it seems to slow down far less, but still slow down.

Answer (score 1):

Try profiling your code with [traceview](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/traceview.html).